# Android storage access framework

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Всем привет, знаю, что уже очень много вопросов на эту тему, однако, как грамотно использовать Android storage access framework. Вот примерно такой:

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 9999)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
         9999 -> {
             Log.e("Test", "Result URI " + data!!.data!!.path) 
         }
    }
}
```

Если быть точнее, то вопрос вот в чем:
Все эти File picker'ы возвращают uri файла. Так вот, например, я хочу создать файл в выбранной папке или открыть выбранный файл как объект типа File(), как это сделать?

P.S.
Пожалуйста, не предлагайте вот такие способы:

```
val uri = data!!.getData()
val file=File(uri.path)
```

Если для данного объекта вызвать метод

```
file.exists()
```

Он вернет false

Comment: Не все Uri являются обьектами файловой системы.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вопрос как раз в том, как с этими URI работать правильно, например, если я хочу создать новый файл или открыть его

Comment: В документации есть примеры, как читать, создавать, удалять, переписывать. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, я их видел, однако мне приходится работать со сторонней библиотекой,  а она, в свою очередь, не позволяет мне делать так, как в тех примерах. Именно она занимается чтением файла, а моя задача его передать туда в виде этого объекта

Answer (score 2):

Как вам правильно сказали в комментариях, не все Uri являются файлами, это может быть например ссылка в сети или вообще запись в БД.

А раз так, то вам нужно правильно определять какие Uri являются файлами, например так:

```
/**
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is file.
 */
public static boolean isFileDocument(final Uri uri) {
    if(uri.toString().startsWith("file://"))
        return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(final Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(final Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(final Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

По хорошему, если Uri являюется одним из указанных типов, то его можно сконвертировать в некое подобие файла. Если нет, скажем это запись в БД в виде BLOB'а то может подойти вариант:

```
 context.getContentResolver().openFile(uri, mode);
```

Если не получается, то на помощь для чтения придет:

```
InputStream is=context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Для записи: `context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);`

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ, как смогу проверю